# During installation can't change directory

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

I try to install mysql db server on windows 10.

Version `mysql-installer-community-5.7.16.0.msi`

During the installation Install MSI does not offer to change the installation directory.

Do I correctly understand that I can't change the installation directory during the installation process?

Comment: Download the .zip file instead

Comment: you may have to change it later using my.ini places under ProgramData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods available, either use ZIP archive to install or you may have to change the datadir variable in my.ini after installation. You can use following steps

1. Complete the installation
2. Identify the config file and then look for related datadir being used, you may used mysql>show variables like ‘datadir’ within mysql to identify datadir or the service details for concerned my.ini
3. Stop the service if it is already running
4. Change the value of datadir in my.ini, it is usually placed under C:\ProgramData\MySQL
5. Copy/move the folder contents to newer location
6. Make sure permissions are provided to user who owns mysql service
7. Start service and verify using mysql>show variables like ‘datadir’

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can make the following steps:

1. Manually create folder `C:\Program files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7`  (this is in 64 bits version)
2. Run the installer normally

Create an empty folder, although is empty folder, makes the installer allow you to choose another location.

Comment: Could you explain in detail how this can be used by the installer? Your last statement is hard to understand.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! @hot2use This results in an additional page in the installer to "resolve the path conflict" and then allows you to change your installation directory. Bizarre choice not to offer changing the dir in the first place, but this will do...